# Is the space-part of a four-vector temporally connected to the time-part and vice-versa?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, vectors

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/is-there-an-official-name-for-lorentz-pairs-like-energy-and-momentum) question made me think about four-vectors. All four-vectors, be it the archetypical time/position vector or the charge-density/current one, the energy/3D-momentum or electric/magnetic fields or potentials (though these are better expressed in a 4x4 tensor), contain a scalar time part, and a 3D vector space part. This can be expanded to tensor obviously, which mixes  both parts.

Can we say that it's the time part that's involved in defining the space part and the space part in defining the time part? For example, the momentum can only be defined by involving time. Likewise, the magnetic field involves the velocity of charge, which is also the case for a charged current. On the other hand, time is defined by changing objects in space, energy is defined by motion in space, or charge by the way how fast objects accelerate in space. Do we see a pattern here?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say that it's the time part that's involved in defining the space part and the space part in defining the time part?

A displacement 4-vector has

- a time-component that has nothing to do with its spatial-components

and

- spatial-components that have nothing to do with its time-component.

So, as an inherent property of a generic 4-vector, the answer to your question is no.

---

Given a 4-vector, its set of components according to a given observer is constructed using the 4-velocity of that observer (and a triad of unit vectors orthogonal to it).

Comment: But how can space exist without time (or time without space)? It's relativity that ties them together. So, a Vierbein has components that are dependence on one another. Not funcionally but conceptually.

Comment: @Felicia I added to my initial post before I saw your comment. I think it may help.

Comment: @Felicia In Newtonian physics, does the x-component of a displacement vector have any relation to the y-component of that displacement vector? We're just focusing on the generic displacement vector... not tied to any specific situation.

Comment: Like I said, not functionally. And neither conceptually. You can vary the numbers indepently from one another. But in SR, because of a finite speed of light, you can't vary space without time, i.e., instantly. Neither you can vary time if a spatial situation of objects changes. But that's philosophy, as I see now. The 3-momentum part, like all spaceparts of momentum, explicitely contain the this time factor. And ain't x mostly a function of time or time a function of x, in GR?

Comment: @Felicia Regardless of the finiteness of the speed of light, a displacement vector (which need not necessarily be associated with a portion of a worldline) can be timelike, null, spacelike, or zero. Such a general 4-vector (which typically has no further constraints) has completely independent components. So, for the generic 4-vector, the answer to the question in the title is “no”.  For other specific 4-vectors, subject to additional constraints, the answer may no longer be “no”… but that’s a different question—not the question in the title.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. Maybe I should have asked about all 4-vectors derived from the archetypical one.

Answer (score 0):

I offer up a different view that does tie space and time together as you are thinking, based on Loop Quantum Gravity.

LQG is an alternative theory of space (alternative to string theory) that is currently being championed by [Physicist Carlo Rovelli](https://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/%7Erovelli/IntroductionLQG.pdf) and others [myself included with this speculative theory](https://vixra.org/abs/2202.0156).  In LQG, space is quantum (or as I like to call it "particulate"), with each particle being extremely small, on the order of 10^-35 metres.  Dr. Don Lincoln from Fermilab made the statement [When you add mass and energy, you can distort the shape of the little volumes of quantum space...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMpkFde3euA&t=71s)  And Arvin Ash noted [When mass and energy are added to the spin foam the shape of the volumes of the spin network is distorted.  This distorts space and time...  This distortion of space and time is what we perceive as gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jKPJa-f3cQ&t=3s)

Working from these two statements, when these LQG particles are distorted by energy near a planet, then they dilate so it takes longer for light to travel. This is a measure of the speed of time and the reason why it slows near a planet. This is the warping of spacetime that we know as gravity.

So to answer your basic question, yes the rate of time is connected intimately with the X,Y,Z axes of space because it is the size of the particles of space that determines the speed of time.